# Find efficiently a file with unknown extension

Tags: python, performance, file

I have a problem that feels easy, but I cannot come up with a satisfying solution.

I have a file structure with a directory containing a very large number of files. The file names are just their index with an unknown extension. For example, the 10th file is "10.pdf" and the 42th file is "42.png". There can be many different extensions.

I need to access the i-th file from python, given index i but not knowing the extension. This will happen a lot, so I should be able to do it efficiently.

Here are the partial solutions I could think about:

1. I can glob the pattern `f"{i}.*"`
   However, I think glob will check every file in the directory? This will be very slow for a large number of files.
2. I can save and preload the full name in a `dict`, in a JSON file like `{..., 10: "10.pdf", ...}`
   This works, but I have to load and keep track of another heavy object. This feels wrong somehow...
3. If I have a list of all allowed extensions, I can just test all possibilities. This feels weird and unnecessary, but that's my best guess for now.

What do you think ? Is one of those proposal the correct way to do it ?

Comment: Before investing time into optimizing this, do you have enough files that you really need anything beyond either the glob or the dict in order to achieve acceptable performance and memory usage?

Comment: I think this is something to solve in the file system itself. Create links (symbolic or hard, I don't think it matters much) named `i` to each `i.whatever` file. Creating the links is a one-time cost, if whatever can *add* files to the directory can take the responsibility for creating the required link for new files.

Comment: About number 2, if the there can't be `10.pdf` and `10.png` then the the stored data can be compacted a great deal, no need to create a full on dict, a simple list would suffice, just store the minimum you need to get the file name, like the extension, or even better just a number with index/key to get said extension, and who need an full on list stored with json that waste a ton of space with useless characters such as space and brackets and etc, just store a byte array... and even if a particular file have multiple extensions, so long they are 8 or less this bytes approach can still work

Comment: @nanofarad To be honest I am not sure. I am writing specs and tests at the moment and I don't have access to the data itself. But tens of millions of files, maybe hundreds, is possible.

Comment: @chepner that's a great idea ! I'll look into it. Thank you!

Comment: @Copperfield, that's also a great point! I'll test your solution in my use case. Thank you!

Comment: I would be honestly concerned about the underlying storage system more than Python itself as many filesystems (and file management tools) do not optimize closely for this use-case. On top of what you're currently doing, you may want to consider *sharding* the directory across multiple directories by some relevant sharding key (e.g. `fileNum % numShards`). This doesn't invalidate your question in any way, since you'll still need to map num -> extension, but you need to also look in a different directory depending on the shard number.

Answer (score 0):

As I think, you only need the file name instead full filename+ext. So, one way is to remove the extension from the file, for example:

```
import os
path = r"Enter your folder's path here"
file_dict = {}


for file in os.listdir(path):
    if os.path.isfile(file): # because os.listdir return both files and folders
        file_name, ext = os.path.splitext(file)
        print(file_name, ext)
```

For example, if your file is '10.pdf' then file_name='10' and ext='.pdf'. Then you can add it to a dictionary for the future:

```
file_dict[file_name] = os.path.join(path, file)
```

Another way is using regular expressions or "re"! if you have a patter(even complex pattern) 're' is awesome! You need to type your desired pattern, for example:

```
import os
import re
path = r"Enter your folder's path here"
file_dict = {}


for file in os.listdir(path):
    if os.path.isfile(file):
        mo = re.search(r'(.*\)(..*)', file)
        file_name, ext = mo.groups()
        print(file_name, ext)
```